# Is "get back" a phrasal verb in "I have to get back to work"?

Tags: pronunciation, phrasal-verbs, intransitive-preposition

For me, it sounds like it is. I would like to know your opinion though. In this sentence: "I have to get back to work.", 'get back' means to return. If I understand correctly when we pronounce phrasal verbs in a sentence we usually stress the particle a bit more than the verb. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, get back is a phrasal verb. you can check this [link](http://www.usingenglish.com/reference/phrasal-verbs/get+back.html) and about stressing, this [link](http://www.macmillandictionaries.com/MED-Magazine/October2005/34-Phrasal-Verbs-Pron.htm#3) can be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Your time is greatly appreciated. I think I was right about the stress. According to the link the particle gets the most stress in this situation.

Comment: I think you are right about where to stress more. Anyway further answers can be helpful.

Comment: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=xFsuwuoMAvU

Answer (score -2):

Yes, this is a phrasal verb and the particle is always stressed.

We use **get** instead of **go** in situations where we're losing time, or running late, or when someone is wasting time at work, school, etc.

[*running late*]

> It's already 9:15 - I need to get to work.

[*wasting time*]

> Stop looking at your phone and get back to work!

Comment: HHmmm. Your example there's no good! When *get* is stressed, *back* won't be. Here, because of the imperative, *get* will be stressed and *back* therefore won't be.

Comment: Hmmmm, your English is perhaps no good because GET is never stressed and BACK is always stressed. In an imperative, you say: Get BACK!  Nobody would ever say GET back!

Comment: But I have to say it's amusing to have my English corrected in Pidgin English!

Comment: Would you care to explain which bit of my comment was in Pidgin English?

Comment: ***Stop** talking **rubb**ish and **get** back to **work**!*

Comment: <--- That's different from *Get **back**!* The meaning's different and there's no content word after **back** in the last example and therefore no other candidate for the nuclear syllable. It is possible to say *get **back** to **work***, in that sentence, but it's less likely.

Comment: Pidgin English: Your example there's no good!

Comment: It means "Your example above (i.e. *there*) is no good" That *no* there's a determiner, if that helps you parse it properly. Or maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: @Araucaria: Oh now I see it. It's a weird construction. Getting back to my example - in my speech, I stress BACK and WORK: [n̩gɛp̚ˌbæk̚ tʰǝˈwɹkʰ]. Apparently you don't, ergo my example's 'no good" for you, but it works for me and all the English speakers who would pronounce it this way. I have no problem with discussion and debate, but absolutes like "no good!" drive me batty

Comment: If large numbers of speakers would pronounce an imperative like that with the stress on *get* then it's no good as an illustrative example, it seems to me! It doesn't matter if it would work for a proportion of people. You've said: *the particle is always stressed*. This isn't true or necessarily  helpful. "The particle is usually stressed" would be fine though, I suppose.

Comment: To illustrate, try "I want to get back early" with a nuclear stress on *early*. If you tap it out on the table you'll find that the stresses are on *want*, *get* and the first syllable of *early*. If you try and put a lot of stress on *back* you'll find that you're making *back* the nuclear syllable and putting the word *early* in the tail (i.e. after the nuclear tone). There's no way of saying it in a natural fashion with a nuclear syllable in early unless *back* isn't stressed.